How to reverse linear blend skinning?
Inside Maya, I have a point in 3D that was deformed using Linear Blend skinning.
I also have access to the joints in their current pose and in their bind pose as well as the weight values.
I would like to inverse the linear blend skinning to get the original position of that point.
I am using this website (MyCustomSkinCluster.cpp) as reference on the Linear blend skinning formula, it works one way but when I try to reverse it to get the original position it doesn't give the correct position.
What would be the correct way to reverse it?
I am currently just changing
mat = preBindMatrix * mat;

to
mat = preBindMatrix.inverse() * mat.inverse();

To inverse the matrices. I can't seem to wrap my head around what's the logic to inverse matrix operations.
Thank you for your help.

Short answer: you can't. Linear blend skinning uses a linear weighted sum which is somewhat lossy. Given the current joint transforms, the skin weights, and the current (deformed) vertex positions; the most you can do is generate a new bind pose based on that configuration. You cannot however retrieve the original undeformed mesh from the current configuration.

I've made a back transform in one of tools for MotionBuilder, but I think in Maya it should be done in a similar way.
The steps should be following

grad a final position of a vertex (deformed)
if the final position is in world space, multiply it by inverse of model transformation matrix to convert into model space
grab influences, weights for a skin cluster

    MDagPathArray influencePaths;
    unsigned int influenceCount = skinCluster.influenceObjects(influencePaths);
    
    MItGeometry geoIter(meshObject);
    MDoubleArray weights;
    skinCluster.getWeights(geoIter.currentItem(), geoIter.component(), weights);


extract influence matrices

MMatrixArray influenceMatrices(influenceCount);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < influenceCount; ++i) {
  MFnDagNode influenceNode(influencePaths[i].node());
  influenceMatrices[i] = influencePaths[i].inclusiveMatrix();
}


compute linear blend skinning deformation matrix for the vertex by accumulating all influence matrices with their weights

MMatrix deformedMatrix;
for (unsigned int vtx = 0; vtx < vertexCount; ++vtx) {
    deformedMatrix.setToIdentity();

    for (unsigned int inf = 0; inf < influenceCount; ++inf) {
        double weight = weights[vtx * influenceCount + inf];
        if (weight > 0.0) {
            // Weighted transformation matrix
            MMatrix weightedMatrix = influenceMatrices[inf] * weight;

            // Add to the deformed matrix
            deformedMatrix += weightedMatrix;
        }
    }

    // Normalize the matrix (if necessary)
    double totalWeight = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int inf = 0; inf < influenceCount; ++inf) {
        totalWeight += weights[vtx * influenceCount + inf];
    }

    if (totalWeight > 0.0) {
        deformedMatrix /= totalWeight;
    }
}


multiply deformed vertex position in model space by inverse of computed deformation matrix

